# How to set the year value in input date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to set just the **year** in my input date

```js
var dateVal = $('#mydate').val();
new Date(dateVal).setFullYear(2015);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="mydate">My input</label> 
<input id="mydate" type="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most effective one, but try this:

```js
function clicked() {
        alert(new Date(document.getElementById("year").value, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00));
    }
```

```html
 
    <input type="number" name="year" min="1000" max="9999" id="year">
<input type="button" onclick="clicked()" value="Click Me!">
```

This gives me a year right. You can change the min and max value of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, Here you can set the year value as required but you cannot show only year to date field as it will be invalid date and you cannot choose date format to show only year. You can show year in normal text input as shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var dateVal = $('#mydate').val();
var now;
if(dateVal) {
  now = new Date(dateVal);
} else {
  now = new Date();
}

  now.setFullYear(2015);
  var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var myDate = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;  // for full date
  $('#mydate').val(myDate);
  $('#myyear').val(now.getFullYear());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="mydate">My input</label> 
<input id="mydate" type="date">
<input id="myyear" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. As only year is not supported in input type date i had taken another input field.

```js
   
$('#mydate').change(function() {
     var dateVal = $('#mydate').val();
     console.log(dateVal);
     getYear = dateVal.split('-');
     $("#year").val(getYear[0]);
   });
```

```html
   
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <label for="mydate">My input</label>
   <input id="mydate" type="date">
   <input id="year" type="text" disabled>
```